# Jackson with JSON : receiving "null" object

Tags: java, json, jackson, uber-api

I need to convert a Uber Products JSON response from [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-products) to a Java object. I am using Jackson for JSON handling. My input JSON looks like:

```
    {
      "products": [
        {
           "capacity": 2,
           "description": "Ride for less with uberPOOL",
           "price_details": {},
           "image": "http://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/car.jpg",
           "display_name": "POOL",
           "product_id": "26546650-e557-4a7b-86e7-6a3942445247",
           "shared": true,
        },
        {
           "capacity": 4,
           "description": "The low-cost Uber",
           "price_details": {
              "distance_unit": "mile",
              "cost_per_minute": 0.26,
              "service_fees": [
                 {
                    "fee": 1.0,
                    "name": "Safe Rides Fee"
                 }
              ],
              "minimum": 5.0,
              "cost_per_distance": 1.3,
              "base": 2.2,
              "cancellation_fee": 5.0,
              "currency_code": "USD"
           },
           "cash_enabled": false,
           "image": "http://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/car.jpg",
           "display_name": "uberX",
           "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
           "shared": false
        }
      ]
    }
```

My entity class looks like:

```
    public class Products {

        @JsonProperty
        private int capacity;
        @JsonProperty
        private String description;
        @JsonProperty
        private String price_details;
        @JsonProperty
        private String image; 
        @JsonProperty
        private Boolean cash_enabled; 
        @JsonProperty
        private Boolean shared; 
        @JsonProperty
        private String short_description; 
        @JsonProperty
        private String display_name;

            //getter, setter methods
    }
```

and wrapper class looks like:

```
    public class ProductsModel{
        private List <Products> product;

        public List<Products> getProduct() {
            return product;
        }
        public void setProduct(List<Products> product) {
            this.product = product;
        }
    }
```

now when i try map the JSON to my wapper class and try to print the products .. it is giving "null" not sure why .. please help to point out why.

```
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    productsModel = mapper.readValue(line1, ProductsModel.class);   
    response.getWriter().println("get products:" + productsModel.getProduct()); //<-- returns null - not sure why
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below Product and ProductsModel class it will work fine.

**Product entiry:**

```
public class Products {

    @JsonProperty
    private int capacity;

    @JsonProperty
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty
    private Map price_details;

    @JsonProperty
    private String image;

    @JsonProperty
    private Boolean cash_enabled;

    @JsonProperty
    private Boolean shared;

    @JsonProperty
    private String short_description;

    @JsonProperty
    private String display_name;
}
```

**ProductsModel wrapper class:**

```
public class ProductsModel {

    private List<Products> products;

    public List<Products> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Products> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

In your code there were two mistakes:

1. The **price_details** value in json is a Object not string hence it should be a **Map** or some **PriceDetails** entity class which contain properties available inside the **price_details** json. In my reply i just used Map.
2. The name of key in **ProductsModel** wrapper class was **product** it should be **products**.

I just made both the changes in Product and ProductsModel class and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you Hokam.... I made changes as you suggested, however still when i try to print the products ..  .. i am still getting NULL.

Comment: Actually, i am getting InvalidFormatException  ............   [INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Boolean from String value 'uberX': only "true" or "false" recognized

Comment: Are you using different JSON then the one which is shared above? I tried with the above one and it is working fine. Share the JSON if it is different.

Comment: Yes, JSON is same, however, it kept giving me error related to "short_description" .. so finally to move ahead i am doing annotation JsonIgnore instead of JsonProperty